# Writing a Discord Bot using Discord.py Rewrite

Tags: python, discord

So currently I have a discord Bot, and I want to make it welcome any new users in #joining and give them the nickname "[0] Member Name". I'm not getting any errors but neither of these functions are working!

EDIT: Re-Wrote Some Code and I'm Now Getting This Error:

EDIT 2: Still Unable to Edit Nicknames, but when a User Leaves the Server I get these errors from the Function to check if the User is a Staff Member. I don't get errors from the message.author, but when the message author leaves, I start getting this error. I tried resetting the message.author when anyone leaves the server but this didn't help! I don't have any ideas on how to stop these errors!

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Evan\Anaconda3\envs\testing\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 270, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/Evan/PycharmProjects/Bot/bot.py", line 107, in on_message
    top_role = message.author.top_role
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'top_role'
```

My New Edited Code vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv

```py
import discord
import asyncio
import time

# id = 630529690792230923
messages = joined = 0

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as: {client.user.name}')
    print(f"User ID: {client.user.id}")
    print('-----')


async def update_stats():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    global messages, joined

    while not client.is_closed():
        try:
            with open("stats.txt", "a") as f:
                f.write(f"Time: {int(time.time())}, Messages: {messages}, Members Joined: {joined}\n"),
            messages = 0
            joined - 0

            await asyncio.sleep(3600)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            await asyncio.sleep(3600)


@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    message_id = payload.message_id
    if message_id == 638155786559684608:
        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g: g.id == guild_id, client.guilds)

        if payload.emoji.name == 'Test':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='new role')
        else:
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=payload.emoji.name)

        if role is not None:
            member = discord.utils.find(lambda m: m.id == payload.user_id, guild.members)
            if member is not None:
                await member.add_roles(role)
                print("done")
            else:
                print("Member Not Found")


@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    message_id = payload.message_id
    if message_id == 638155786559684608:
        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g: g.id == guild_id, client.guilds)

        if payload.emoji.name == 'Test':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='new role')
        else:
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=payload.emoji.name)

        if role is not None:
            member = discord.utils.find(lambda m: m.id == payload.user_id, guild.members)
            if member is not None:
                await member.remove_roles(role)
                print("done")


@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    global joined
    joined += 1
    rule_channel = member.guild.get_channel(channel_id=630530486858547223)
    newusermessage = f"""Welcome to CB:NL {member.mention}! Have a Great Time And Make Sure to Look At {rule_channel}"""
    channel = member.guild.get_channel(channel_id=630563931412496434)

    role = member.guild.get_role(role_id=630533613947060244)
    if member is not None:
        await member.add_roles(role)
        print("done")

    await member.edit(str([f"[0] {member.display_name}"]))

    await channel.send(newusermessage)


@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    discord.message.author = member


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global messages
    messages += 1
    id = client.get_guild(630529690792230923)
    bad_words = ["test"]
    channels = ["bot-commands", "staff-general"]
    pn = 1
    author = message.author
    top_role = message.author.top_role
    staff_role = message.author.guild.get_role(role_id=630532857655328768)

    if top_role > staff_role:

        if message.content.startswith == "-clean":
            pass

        if str(message.channel) in channels:
            if message.content.find("-hello") != -1:
                await message.channel.send("Hi")

            elif message.content == "-status":
                await message.channel.send(f"""# of Members: {id.member_count}""")

    else:
        if message.author.bot is not 1:
            print(f"""{message.author} tried to do command {message.content}""")
            await message.channel.send(f"Error, {message.author.mention}. You Cannot Do That!")


client.loop.create_task(update_stats())
```

Comment: `client.send_message()` - first argument should be the destination (in this case your channel instance). Use `client.send_message(channel, f"Welcome to CB:NL {member.mention}!")`. Also when you compare channel to id, you should use `channel.id`, which is a string property.

Comment: @eyllanesc I've done some edits and rewritten some things, still stuck on some error messages though!

Comment: Sorry, '@'ed the wrong person! @Ko Revised my Code

Answer (score 1):

I'll respond in answer, because there are multiple mistakes in your code and it's hard to put into the comment. You can comment under this post if you get another error.

---

```
role = discord.utils.get(discord.Guild.roles, name="Member")
```

The error is where you retrieve the role by name Member. It's better to get the role by ID, you can do that using `member.guild.get_role(630533613947060244)`. The error is that `discord.Guild.roles` is not an iterable property.

---

```
nick = discord.utils.get(str(member.nick))
```

Not sure what is your intention there, you can use `nick = member.nick` to get a string with member's nickname.

---

To edit the nickname you should use:

```
await member.edit(nick=f"[0] {member.display_name}")
```

---

> AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'top_role'

You get this error because you want to access `top_role` attribute on instance of `discord.User`, but only `discord.Member` has this attribute defined. When someone leaves the server you get the User instance instead of the Member instance.

```
if isinstance(message.author, discord.Member):
  top_role = message.author.top_role
else:
  top_role = None   # top role not available, user has no roles
```

Comment: The Auto-Nickname part still isn't working as I still don't understand how to use member.edit

Comment: @GardenGnome164 Use it like this: `await member.edit(nick="new nick")` See my edit.

Comment: Thanks! It's working now! Still having some issues with the last part though. ;-;

Comment: Which last part specifically? Try to describe the problem more in detail by editing your question.

Comment: The Last bit that checks to make sure top_role > staff_role is giving me some errors when the member leaves.

Comment: @GardenGnome164 Check the last edit, it's because top_role is not defined if the user left the server. You can set it to `None` and then you could change the condition like this  `top_role is not None and  top_role > staff_role `